# the_title filter applying to menu items

Tags: title

I want to create a simple function to call the logged-in user's username along with the word "Wishlist".

It seems to be working but it also changes the menu item titles!

```
function customize_wishlist_title( $title ){
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$loggeduser = $current_user->user_login;
if ( is_page( 258 ) ) {
        $title = '<span class="username">'.$loggeduser.'\'s'.'</span>'.'&nbsp;'.'<span>Wishlist</span>';
    } 
return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title','customize_wishlist_title', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `in_the_loop()` conditional tag to make sure you are modifying the title inside the Loop and to prevent the hook changing titles somewhere else:

```
function customize_wishlist_title( $title ){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $loggeduser = $current_user->user_login;
    // give attention to the following condition:
    if ( is_page( 258 ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = '<span class="username">'.$loggeduser.'\'s'.'</span>'.'&nbsp;'.'<span>Wishlist</span>';
    } 
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title','customize_wishlist_title', 10, 2);
```

See [`in_the_loop()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop) reference.